# IndexOutOfBoundsException in Spring Data MongoDB Repository

Tags: mongodb, spring-roo, spring-data

Trying my hand at Spring Roo with MongoDB, but I am having issues with the Spring Data Repositories find methods.  My repository looks like this:

```
package com.sample.test.repositories;

import com.sample.test.domain.SiteUser;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.layers.repository.mongo.RooMongoRepository;

@RooMongoRepository(domainType = SiteUser.class)
public interface SiteUserRepository {

    public List<SiteUser> findAll();

    public List<SiteUser> findByLoginId();

    public List<SiteUser> findByRealId();
}
```

However, when I try to call any of the find methods, I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.data.repository.query.ParameterOutOfBoundsException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.Parameters.getParameter(Parameters.java:168)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.Parameters.getBindableParameter(Parameters.java:238)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ParametersParameterAccessor.getBindableValue(ParametersParameterAccessor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ParametersParameterAccessor$BindableParameterIterator.next(ParametersParameterAccessor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.ConvertingParameterAccessor$ConvertingIterator.next(ConvertingParameterAccessor.java:187)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.ConvertingParameterAccessor$ConvertingIterator.nextConverted(ConvertingParameterAccessor.java:195)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryCreator.from(MongoQueryCreator.java:216)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryCreator.create(MongoQueryCreator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryCreator.create(MongoQueryCreator.java:48)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:109)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.PartTreeMongoQuery.createQuery(PartTreeMongoQuery.java:69)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:301)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy75.findByLoginId(Unknown Source)
    at com.thirtytwopasteight.xchange.services.UserServiceImpl.findSiteUsersByLoginIdEquals(UserServiceImpl.java:39)
    at com.sample.test.authentication.LocalUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(LocalUserDetailsService.java:32)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:132)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:194)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at com.springsource.insight.collection.tcserver.request.HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.traceNextValve(HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.java:116)
    at com.springsource.insight.collection.tcserver.request.HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.invoke(HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.Parameters.getParameter(Parameters.java:166)
    ... 59 more
org.springframework.data.repository.query.ParameterOutOfBoundsException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.Parameters.getParameter(Parameters.java:168)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.Parameters.getBindableParameter(Parameters.java:238)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ParametersParameterAccessor.getBindableValue(ParametersParameterAccessor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ParametersParameterAccessor$BindableParameterIterator.next(ParametersParameterAccessor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.ConvertingParameterAccessor$ConvertingIterator.next(ConvertingParameterAccessor.java:187)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.ConvertingParameterAccessor$ConvertingIterator.nextConverted(ConvertingParameterAccessor.java:195)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryCreator.from(MongoQueryCreator.java:216)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryCreator.create(MongoQueryCreator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryCreator.create(MongoQueryCreator.java:48)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:109)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.PartTreeMongoQuery.createQuery(PartTreeMongoQuery.java:69)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:301)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy75.findByLoginId(Unknown Source)
    at com.sample.test.services.UserServiceImpl.findSiteUsersByLoginIdEquals(UserServiceImpl.java:39)
    at com.sample.test.authentication.LocalUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(LocalUserDetailsService.java:32)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:132)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:194)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at com.springsource.insight.collection.tcserver.request.HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.traceNextValve(HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.java:116)
    at com.springsource.insight.collection.tcserver.request.HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.invoke(HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.Parameters.getParameter(Parameters.java:166)
    ... 59 more
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way to do any of this, as up to now I have always dealt with JPA Entities, and this is my first attempt at Mongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reference a property in your query method you need to pass in a parameter to the method, which you obviously don't do here. I would have expected a more semantic exception of course. So would you mind filing a ticket in the Spring Data MongoDB JIRA?

Comment: Duh!  That makes total sense.  I will file a JIRA for it.  Thanks!